# Can an instructor ask students to write a letter of recommendation for them (the instructor)?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I am considering applying for two new jobs. I love where I am now, but these opportunities would be better for me as they would come with higher compensation and are closer to where I live. One idea I had was to ask a couple of my best students to write a letter recommending me for these positions. Is that ethical? I do not need them per se (I have others I can ask), but I was wondering about this idea. It seems like this school is looking for student-centered instructors, so I thought this might be a way to set me apart. Thoughts?

Comment: Could you please specify the country? Customs about letters of recommendation vary a lot by country.

Comment: Whether or not you *can* do this, I definitely don't think you *should*.  It will not help your application and will probably sink it.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I'd say a place where this sinks an aplication has definitely failed.

Comment: Could you please edit the question to clarify whether these students are your *current* or *former* students?

Comment: @Thomas They haven't failed at all. The answers explain why asking students for references shows poor judgement of the staff-student boundary, (e.g., current students may feel they can't say no to somebody who has power over them; former students might want a reference from the asker so there are _quid-pro-quo_ worries).

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I disagree. There are many situations where it is ethically appropriate. If I want to know whether a course is good or not I'd rather ask a student then a collegue (in my country, no collegue ever came by my lessons or talked with me about teaching). Sure, there are many situations where asking a student is inappropriate, however , an instituation which assumes that students' references are in general inappropriate, have failed and cannot care too much about teaching quality.

Comment: @Thomas The issues of caring about teaching quality and finding it appropriate to get a letter of recommendation from a student have basically nothing to do with one another.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I disagree. Only students can reasonably speak about teaching quality.

Comment: @Thomas Who can reasonably speak about teaching quality and who can reasonably write a letter of reference are two completely different issues. Please stop conflating them.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: If attaching a recomendation letter from the only persons who can talk ahout teaching quality is a reason to sink an application, the institution can not care too much about teaching quality. As regarding formalties of reference letters, while some students can indeed not be expected to write a reference letters, I beloeve many students could be trusted to write an appropriate letter.

Comment: @Thomas The answers explain why it is wholly inappropriate to ask for a LoR from a student. It doesn't matter if students are the people who are best placed to give an opinion on any particular subject; asking for a LoR is not an appropriate way of soliciting that opinion.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: The answers explain, why it might be inappropriate. Those reasons are not applicable at all times (and especially not in all cultures). E.g. I would feel comfortable and totally not coerced to write recommendation letters for all of my former high school and university teachers. (In fact, I have been asked already.) If an institution automatically concludes that something inappropriate must have been going on because there is a student's letter, they can't be too interested in teaching quality.

Comment: @Thomas I disagree but thanks for addressing my point.

Answer (score 16):

As others say, there are good reasons not to get reference letters from students: they are biased to please you, don’t know how to write references, and it might be perceived as cherry picking (you’re in fact an awful teacher but one or two students like you).

If you want to offer insights about what students think of you, why not use your teaching evaluations? If you’re indeed an excellent educator, this should reflect in your evaluations. It’s also acceptable to offer snippets from written course evaluations: while this is still a bit of cherry picking, at the very least it’s unbiased. However, I would check your institution’s policy regarding this practice. Some universities are ok with it, others may not be.

Finally, if you want to show you’re a great educator l suggest indicating how you go the extra mile: participating and organizing student events, mentoring, volunteer work etc.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your answer. Unfortunately, I haven't gotten any official teaching evaluation results from students at all since I have been at my current institution. No one has really been able to tell me why, but from what I have heard, it is not just me.

Comment: In that case @Brad I’d suggest getting references from department heads/deans that’d attest to your teaching greatness...

Comment: @Brad Does your institution use end-of-term surveys for the students to fill out evaluating their lecturers' teaching? If so, have you been told what your score on those was? They're usually one of your Key Performance Indicators, so I'd be pretty concerned if they're not giving you access to them - like "brush up your resume and start looking for another job somewhere else right now" concerned.

Comment: To be fair, *all* letters are cherry-picked by design (but of course that still leaves your other good points).

Comment: *"Why not use your teaching evaluations?* Possibly because, well, teaching evaluations aren't typically written in professional prose for a job application...

Comment: I wrote mine in my teaching statement, worked for me, several times.

Comment: @Mehrdad All the teaching evaluations I've received have included numerical scores.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Numerical scores can substitute for a letter of recommendation?

Comment: @Mehrdad Huh? You'd quote them in your teaching statement and/or covering letter.

Comment: To clarify, my teaching statement consisted of more than just a single table with my evaluation scores

Comment: @Spark: Letters from department heads/deans can also be cherry-picked (and most of the time, they cannot be a reasonable judge of your teaching quality).

Comment: @Thomas if there’s an associate dean for undergraduate studies or something of the sort then they should be good I suppose? Also all references are obviously biased (hopefully towards you!), my point is that if your department head writes a bad letter there’s little you can do, a student on the other hand...

Answer (score 6):

From my perspective (as a student who has for many year been involved in students' union work and higher education quality and development), I would not recommend it. Although I very much appreciate the weight you give to the students' opinion, I see a number of potential negative consequences - but of course all of them are dependent on the system or country you are working in.

Firstly, I think it would be very difficult for these students to actually say no. The dependency of a student on their teacher for evaluation and grades goes further than I think most university employees realise. My experience is that students are, with or without reason, still very much afraid to do anything that might upset their teachers. Saying no to such a question is basically equal to saying that you are a bad teacher, which is the last thing a student want to say to someone who will set their grade or influence their further career.

Secondly, I believe that it would not tell your prospective employer very much, as every teacher will have some students that really like them and others that don't. As long as you have picked which students write the letter of recommendation it will not actually say anything on the proportions between these groups.

If you want a letter of recommendation from the students (which in itself, I want to stress once more, indicates that you have an interested in the best of the students' and are probably a committed teacher) I would recommend contacting the local students' union  or students' association. They hopefully are independent enough to give an "objective" letter, and if they have the time and the resources to contact students, they can provide something of this kind. For this reason, in my students' union we award different prizes to appreciated teachers and mentors, which apart from showing general appreciation and gratitude for often hard and unrewarded work effectively fills this exact purpose.

Comment: The course evaluations should of course be submitted anyway. However, that there is a bias is an inherent feature of a recomendation letter: The readers should exect that one took the best recommendator for them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have been more clear that it would be former students only that I would ask, but I still think it is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a good idea, for several reasons. First, even if you ask students who are literally *former* students, they themselves may need or want a recommendation letter or similar from you in the future, so they are coerced.

Second, almost surely students have no idea how to write effective letters of recommendation for any purpose... There are often-implicit stylistic expectations.

Third, in particular, often letters of recommendation should concern predictions for the applicant's future, based on the letter writer's prior experience with such future-predicted-from-past. Students will not have any such information (e.g., how likely the applicant is to succeed in grad school, as an extreme case).

Fourth, the people reading your file will wonder why you did not have more senior people writing letters, no matter what the students say. The people reading those letters will suspect you of having dubious judgement about how things work...

Even if you've not had student evaluations of your teaching, hopefully (?) some faculty member in your department will have visited one of your classes, and can give an opinion on your teaching (based on broader experience than any student would have).

Comment: Where in the world do other faculty members visit one's classes? Is this a thing in the US?

Comment: @Thomas It's a thing in Australia, at least in primary/secondary education. Not sure about tertiary, though.

Comment: @Thomas, yes, in the U.S., e.g., at my research-oriented big state university, more-senior faculty visit a few of the junior faculty classes to form an appraisal different from student evaluations, which are also required nowadays.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, this is also a thing at my research-oriented big state university, and has been at least since I went up for tenure 15 years ago.

Comment: @JeffE: Wow, that's great! We neither have mandatory student evaluations nor anybody caring at all about how a new instructor teaches.

Comment: It's a thing i nthe UK, too.

Answer (score 2):

It is never ethical or appropriate for someone who has power over someone else (you determine their grades) to ask that person to do anything that is not already determined by the nature of the specific relationship that defines that power.

You can ask your students to do particular assignments. You *cannot* ask them on dates, for loans of money, to renovate your house, baby sit your children, or to write you letters of recommendation.

For "Instructor", try substituting "Judge", "Doctor", "Therapist", "Manager", "Law Enforcement officer", and then substitute any other actions that are not specifically defined by those roles and think carefully about the possible implications.

Answer (score 2):

I wish this was not a bad idea (but it is).

You could consider writing a paragraph in your cover letter or teaching statement wishing that you could ask students to recommend you but know you can't. Then perhaps describe the progress some particular students made, and why you think you helped that happen.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally lean to NOT soliciting such letters.

Most schools have some sort of standardized course evaluations.  Thus, your teaching record sort of speaks for itself.  If you feel the need to highlight some issues, perhaps you can quote comments from your course evaluations, and use them to put together a nice story.  That said, everybody will be aware that such a story will be using cherry picked comments.

As a graduate of a program, since left, I have been invited to submit a tenure letter for a prof up for tenure.  I assume the tenure boards have a procedure for getting a list of potential student support letters and fairly choosing who they invite to submit.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is ethical if and only if it is clear that there are no (positive or negative) consequences for the students if they accept/decline/write positive/write negative things.
In particular, if you will still grade your students in the near future, the students may feel pressured to accept and to write a positive letter. This would not be ethical. In this case, you might want to consider asking ex-students instead.

(A random thought: Is it really the best to ask the best students and not some students who made a lot of progress due to your teaching? I don't know the answer to this question.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To me, I think of my best students as the ones who made the most progress. I would only ask former students if I did this, but I think it's probably a bad idea all around.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this once in the past.  I was a graduate student TAing in a course taught by an assistant prof who was applying for promotion (and also tenure at the same time).  I was already senior TA for the course at the time, and this was for promotion within the University, where such letters from a senior graduate student could have some weight.

The issue is: what can these students say that will provide insight for an employer?  In my case it was easy to talk about the course organization, the undergraduate response to the course and other factors important to a Faculty Dean and a promotion committee, but what context and insight can these students bring to your advantage in the application process?

Comment: I'm not sure this is really comparable. As a TA, you're in an employee-like role, which is a very different position to being a student taking the class.